# Changing the way books are referenced in biblatex-phys

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently writing my thesis and have been struggling a lot with the references. After reading a lot (of StackExchange) I decided to change to `biblatex`/bibtex. I'm currently using the `physrj` style is equal to the phys style with a few minor changes (achieved with the help of current answers on this forum).

I would like to change one final thing, but it isn't obvious to me how. I would like to change the way books are listed from:

> T.L. Wilson, K. Rohlfs, and S. Huttemeister, *Tools of radio
>   astronomy*, 6th ed. (Springer, Heidelberg, 2013).

to:

> T.L. Wilson, K. Rohlfs, and S. Huttemeister, *Tools of radio
>   astronomy*, 6<sup>th</sup> edition, Springer, Heidelberg (2013).

Where the edition and location are optional / if available.

What would be required to change this? Thanks for the help.

My current MWE for figuring this out:

```
\begin{filecontents}{Books.bib}
@BOOK{TRA,
   author = {{Wilson}, T.~L. and {Rohlfs}, K. and {H\"{u}ttemeister}, S.},
    title = "{Tools of radio astronomy}",
 keywords = {RADIO ASTRONOMY},
publisher = {Springer},
location = {Heidelberg},
edition = 6,
     year = 2013}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sorting=none,style=phys,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Books.bib}

\begin{document}
We cite a book \citep{TRA}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get superscript ordinals with

```
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
    \begingroup
    \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>100\do{\advance\@tempcnta-100\relax}%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>20
      \@whilenum\@tempcnta>9\do{\advance\@tempcnta-10\relax}%
    \fi
    \textsuperscript{\ifcase\@tempcnta th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}%
    \endgroup}%
}
\makeatother
```

To get "edition" instead of "ed.", load the package with the `abbreviate=false` option.

The brackets finally are modified with

```
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{organization+date}{%
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sorting=none,style=phys,natbib=true,backend=bibtex, abbreviate=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{TRA,
   author = {Wilson, T. L. and Rohlfs, K. and H\"{u}ttemeister, S.},
  title = "{Tools of radio astronomy}",
  publisher = {Springer},  
  location = {Heidelberg},
  edition = 6,
  year = 2013,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
    \begingroup
    \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>100\do{\advance\@tempcnta-100\relax}%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>20
      \@whilenum\@tempcnta>9\do{\advance\@tempcnta-10\relax}%
    \fi
    \textsuperscript{\ifcase\@tempcnta th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}%
    \endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{organization+date}{%
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit
}

\begin{document}
We cite a book \citep{TRA}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> <sup>1</sup> T. L. Wilson, K. Rohlfs, and S. Hüttemeister, *Tools of radio astronomy*, 6<sup>th</sup> edition, Springer, Heidelberg (2013).